# Hive external table: what if the table is accessed during the underlying directory is being updated

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, hiveql

I am using a hive external table which is off a folder in S3 or HDFS. Once a day the folder will be fully refreshed with new set of files and I can't stop the table from being accessed by others when that happens. This will be very rare because of the update time being in off hours but it can happen.

Is there a way to handle this update without any interruption? I can think of a solution alternating two S3 (or HDFS) locations and running "create external table" command in each time with the alternate S3 location but I am not sure whether there is an elegant solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you ever find a more elegant solution? that was the way I was thinking of doing it since we have users querying the external table via presto continually while the write process can take up to 10 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No workaround or handling required , because `hive` takes care of it automatically via `locks`. For a non-partitioned table When the table is being read, a `S(shared)` lock is acquired, whereas an `X(Exclusive)` lock is acquired for all other operations (insert into the table, alter table of any kind etc.). What query can face is slight delay in getting result, untill lock is released. For reference : [Hive Locking](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking)

Comment: But does lock applies to Hive External table? My understanding is locking only possible for hive managed table. We are facing issues because of concurrent read/write on Hive External table.

Comment: **@Luniam** Since the given [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking) bears no mention of `Hive` *managed* or *external* table, I would say yes, **locks apply to external tables**. Moreover if they didn't apply to Hive external table, then reading / altering etc an external table without running into concurrency problems would've been pretty much impossible